# How can I copy IText styles for definite chars

Tags: fabricjs

For example, we have an IText "text1" with underline from 2nd till 4th char.

We need to copy its complete style to "text2" like this:

[image]

So here we must insert some function like getStyleDeclaration or getSelectionStyles for "text1" and setSelectionStyles for "text2", but I still can't make it work.

```
var text1 = new fabric.IText('text1', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
});

text1.setSelectionStyles({ underline: true, }, 2, 4);

var text2 = new fabric.IText('text2', {
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
});

function createCanvas(id) {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);
    canvas.add(text1);
    canvas.add(text2);
    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `styles` property in text object

```js
const styles = text1.styles;
```

top-level properties -> line numbers, 2nd-level properties - charater numbers

In your case you'll get

```js
{
  "0": { // line number
    "2":{ // charater number
      "underline":true
    },
    "3":{ // charater number
      "underline":true
    }
  }
}
```

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#styles

Comment: Thank you! It was much easier than I thought. I was trying to use getSelectionStyles  or something like it. But it simply works with: 
         text2.set({
            styles:text1.styles
        });